# Read body from POST request with Apache http server

Tags: apache

Is there a easy way, how to read the body-value (payload) from a POST request on Apache Http Server (httpd) and hold the value in a variable (e.g. env-var).

What I need is to reflect the incomming body-value (payload) as a value of cookie.

Something like Reflector (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_reflector.html). But the Reflector only reflects the request-payload as response-payload and not value of a cookie.

Any ideas?